# How to get the exact value using excel function or VBA in Two Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hy, I am using a spreadsheet template, to calculate the Franchise Fee and Market Fee on each sale. The idea is that I will pay the franchise fee onetime, either in multiple sales or in a single sale and the total franchise fee should be only $3000, not less or greater when the fee will $3000, I will not bound to pay franchise fee on other sales. This scenario is the same for the market fee, but the market fee which I will pay is $20,000, and if I paid this fee in single or multiple sales, after this, I will not bound to pay this fee. I am trying it to solve it using the formula below but it is not giving me the exact amount. It is exceeding the limit.

```
=IF(SUM($H$9:H9)>3000,0,G10*$H$6) and =IF(SUM($I$9:I9)>20000,0,G10*$J$6)
```

The Sheet layout is as under.

[image]

So I need the total of each fee should be $3000 and $20,000 for each category respectively. The breakup of the fee will be based on the Fee Rate written in Cell H6 and J6 respectively. I tried nested Ifs but could not find the exact amount. Any suggestion,s, please. Thanks

Here is more concise info.

[image]

Comment: Instead of showing us the entire spreadsheet could you narrow this down to the **minimal** amount of data needed to answer the question. I.E. show a handful of inputs and the expected outputs. The problem is a little confusing just by text and the spreadsheet has too much info.

Comment: @urdearboy Please I posted the entire sheet to see how I am working. But the main target columns are shade columns H and I only. The input is given above in the same column and output is given in the same columns h and I but the problem is that the total of column H is $3321 which should be $3000 and a total of column I is $20,030 which should be $20,000.

Comment: Try `=IF(SUM($H$9:H9)>=3000, 0, MIN(3000 - SUM($H$9:H9),  G10*$H$6))`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit the last payment to `Max - Current Sum`

ie.

```
=IF(SUM($H$9:H9)>=3000, 0, MIN(3000 - SUM($H$9:H9),  G10*$H$6))
```